# While creating a yaml pipeline, can we commit yaml file to a branch other than master?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

While committing a newly created yaml pipeline, can I save it to a branch other than master ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not able to** directly switch an existing branch (other than master)when create a new YAML file.

You will only get two choice:

- Commit directly to the master branch
- Create a new branch for this commit

[image]

It's by designed.

As a workaround, you could choose to commit it to a new temporary branch, then copy the generated `azurepipeline.yaml` file to your target branch such as dev.

Then when you create some new pipelines, you could also choose it based on branch.